# facebook login NotImplementedException error

Tags: c#, facebook, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

im making facebook login into  my window phone 8.1 . when click the login button it break the application age me this

> An exception of type 'System.NotImplementedException' occurred in
>   mypriject.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Not implemented
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

then take me to this 
app.g.i.cs page  and highlight this line

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
```

**this is my code pls help me **

```
    public sealed partial class BlankPage1 : Page
{
    FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient();
    string AccessToken = null;
    public BlankPage1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
    /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string redirect_url="https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_seccess.html";
        var loginURL = fb.GetLoginUrl(new{
            client_id ="**myapp id here**",
            redirect_uri = redirect_url,
            response_type ="token",
            scope ="email,publish_stream,user_groups"


        });
          var res= await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None,loginURL,new Uri(redirect_url)  );
        if(res.ResponseStatus==WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
        {
            var callback = new Uri(res.ResponseData.ToString());
            var token = fb.ParseOAuthCallbackUrl(callback);
            AccessToken = token.AccessToken;
            await new MessageDialog("AccessToken").ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Windows phone 8.1 AuthenticateAsync will not work
use this

WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(loginURL ,null WebAuthenticationOptions.None);